# React native ios build failed 'EXUpdates/EXUpdatesDevLauncherController.h' file not found

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, expo

I'm trying to build app on my device IOS and I get this error:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/hZS86.png

Any solution please ?

**Package versions**

"expo-dev-client": "0.8.4",

**Environment info**

```
System:
OS: macOS 11.2.3
Shell: 5.8 - /bin/zsh
Binaries:
Node: 14.15.3 - /var/folders/nn/tt3qwcv969n5lbty3zp_x2jw0000gn/T/yarn--1652863077265-0.08056305255158125/node
Yarn: 1.22.10 - /var/folders/nn/tt3qwcv969n5lbty3zp_x2jw0000gn/T/yarn--1652863077265-0.08056305255158125/yarn
npm: 8.9.0 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v14.15.3/bin/npm
Managers:
CocoaPods: 1.11.3 - /usr/local/bin/pod
SDKs:
iOS SDK:
Platforms: iOS 14.5, DriverKit 20.4, macOS 11.3, tvOS 14.5, watchOS 7.4
Android SDK:
API Levels: 29, 30, 31
Build Tools: 29.0.2, 30.0.0, 30.0.2, 31.0.0
System Images: android-29 | Intel x86 Atom_64, android-30 | Google Play Intel x86 Atom
IDEs:
Android Studio: 2020.3 AI-203.7717.56.2031.7678000
Xcode: 12.5.1/12E507 - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
npmPackages:
expo: ^44.0.4 => 44.0.6
react: 17.0.1 => 17.0.1
react-dom: 17.0.1 => 17.0.1
react-native: 0.64.3 => 0.64.3
react-native-web: 0.17.1 => 0.17.1
npmGlobalPackages:
eas-cli: 0.47.0
expo-cli: 5.2.0
Expo Workflow: bare
```

Answer (score 1):

Solved with this command `expo install expo-updates`